# Grouping the content of nested tuples

Tags: python, python-2.7

please can anyone help me with this code snippet below

```
lst1 = [('1','2',{"v" : 5, "a" : 3}),('7','9',{"v" : 7, "a" : 3}),('3','4',{"v" : 4, "a" : 3}),('1','6',{"v" : 0, "a" : 3}),('2','9',{"v" : 4, "a" : 3})]

lst2 = [[('1','2'),('2','9')], [('1','6'),('7','9')]]
vol = [] 

for elem in lst2:
    for sub_e in elem:
        for l in lst1:
            if  l[0:2] == sub_e:
                vol.append(l[2]["v"])
```

Gave the output:

```
[5, 4, 0, 7]
```

But is there a way to rewrite it so the output will be so:

```
[[5, 4], [0, 7]]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it as follows:

```
lst1 = [('1','2',{"v" : 5, "a" : 3}),('7','9',{"v" : 7, "a" : 3}),('3','4',{"v" : 4, "a" : 3}),('1','6',{"v" : 0, "a" : 3}),('2','9',{"v" : 4, "a" : 3})]

lst2 = [[('1','2'),('2','9')], [('1','6'),('7','9')]]
vol = [] 

for i,elem in enumerate(lst2):             #changed to enumerate
    vol.append([])                         #added empty list for each outer loop
    for sub_e in elem:
        for l in lst1:
            if  l[0:2] == sub_e:
                vol[i].append(l[2]["v"])   #changed vol to vol[i]

>>> print vol
[[5, 4], [0, 7]]
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be better if you could convert the `lst1` to a dictionary like this

```
d = {item[:2]:item[2]["v"] for item in lst1}
print [[d[item] for item in items if item in d] for items in lst2]
# [[5, 4], [0, 7]]
```